# How disassemblers maintain the value of registers while analyzing object files?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering

When we analyze object files using [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/) or any disassembler, we put break points into it. At any time it shows the current state of registers. There can be many programs running in background. Each of these programs will also use these registers and can change their value.

How does disassembler maintains the value of registers for our program when other processes may be continuously changing it?

Comment: The OS does, not the debugger. The debugger simply asks the OS to perform stuff, such as query register values, insert breakpoints, examine memory, etc. See [man ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)

Comment: the processor knows the state of the registers and the debugger (gdb, etc) generally talks to an on board debugger, logic in the chip/processor, and that inspects the chip and passes that to the debugger (gdb, etc).  gdb and others might have instruction set simulators but that is not how they work when you are debugging code on a chip.

Comment: Just to clarify, whether being debugged or not, each process (to be exact, each thread inside each process) has its own private copy of all the registers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disassemblers like `objdump -d` do *not* run the program and don't have register values.  All they have is the machine code, so they can print which registers each instruction uses, but not what value it will hold when the instruction runs.

Any given instruction (like `dec edx`) could run multiple times over the life of the program, with multiple different values for EDX.  So obviously you can't just statically print a single register value for an instruction in a disassembly listing.

---

**You're asking about *debuggers***, which do actually run the program as well as stopping it at breakpoints or single-stepping.

In a multi-tasking OS like Linux, MacOS, or Windows, the OS provides system calls to trace another process, e.g. Linux `ptrace`.  This lets GDB insert breakpoints, or single-step.  And when the target process is stopped, GDB can use `ptrace` to read the saved architectural state (register values).

Running multiple tasks on one CPU is done by the OS, with "**context switches**" that save register state for the old task, and restore state for the new task.  **Each task has its own register state that's loaded into the architectural registers whenever it's actually running.**

This is basic Operating Systems stuff, get a textbook or google some of these keywords if you want to learn more.